# Remove an entire Untangle package?

Tags: untangle

While installing Untangle 9 I accidently installed the "premium" package and the "lite" package. I only wanted the "lite" package, and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to remove a package group from an Untangle router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no options in the GUI to remove package groups.

To remove them one by one (doesn't take that long), just open each package from your rack(s), then at the bottom left you will see a remove button.

A fresh install would also wipe them, but I would just remove them one by one.

Comment: Oh well, it's better than being forced to reinstall I suppose...